# How do I scale database ORM in Sails application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js, scalability

I want to scale the database of a Sails application. I have 2 ideas:
- Use Amazon RDS. 
- Use MySQL Master/Slave

However, I don't know how to apply 2 options in a Sails application?

Comment: What have you tried so far with this 2 options? Can you share a specific problem? Its a general opinion based question.

Comment: For designing a scalable Sails application to serve many requests in the futures, I googled on this. I only got the answer for using:
- Load Balancer
- Multi-instances of Sails server
- Use Redis to share session and socket information between Sails instances.

However I realize that the Database ORM is bottleneck of Sails application. I can only config to use 1 instance for database ORM in the file config/connection.js. What happens when I have 1 instance MySQL Master and 3 instances of MySQL slave? or How to config to connect to Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `adapter` to handle specific database, also with it's own specific configuration. [Here how to do that](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/adapters/adapters.md).

But, ORM is designed to simplify our works with some abstraction, not to achieve low level performance tuning. So, besides the question is too broad, if the question is "can it ...", yes it can, but does it effective and efficient? Low level performance tuning between one company and another may be different, so `ORM` stuff will not fasten our works, it will slow down our works.

My `answer` about how to scale that is simple, don't use ORM/ Waterline. Just write down your own model which controller, services, etc. can interact with.